# jQuery - find a class exist and return true/false

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I want to check if class exists inside a child of `li` and if class exists return `true` or `defined`.

**HTML**

```
<li class="show-more">
<a> if found selected then add to this</a>
<ul>
<li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
<li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
<li><a class="selected"> sub-menu</a></li>
<li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

here is my code, but wont return true or false, it return the url of anchor

```
var active_sub_menu = $('li.show-more ul li').find('selected');

alert(active_sub_menu);
if(typeof active_sub_menu == 'defined'){
    $('li.show-more > a').addClass('selected');
}
```

please dont suggest to use CSS, I just need javascript

Comment: `find('selected')` and as you can see `'selected'` !== `'.selected'`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Go for `.hasClass()` or `length`:

```
if ( $("selector").length ) {   /*EXISTS (greater than 0) */  }
```

or

```
if ( $("selector")[0] ) {   /*EXISTS (not undefined) */  }
```

or

```
if ( $("selector").hasClass("someClass") ) {   /*EXISTS (has class) */  }
```

```js
$('.show-more').each(function () {

  if ( $(this).find("li a.seleted").length ) {
    console.log('FOUND');
    $(this).children("a").addClass('selected'); // Make main anchor  also selected 
  } else {
    console.log('NOT FOUND');
  }

});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="show-more">
    <a> if found .selected then add also to this anchor</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
      <li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
      <li><a class="selected"> sub-menu</a></li>
      <li><a> sub-menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: please check updated question, there is an anchor tag just after list tag and that is the place where I want to add selected class if found in its child `ul li a`

Answer (score 4):

```
if($('li.show-more ul li').hasClass('defined')) {
    $('li.show-more > a').addClass('selected');
}
```

I assume that's what you intended with [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)?

Another option:

```
var active_sub_menu = $('li.show-more ul li').find('.selected');
if(active_sub_menu.length) {
    $('li.show-more > a').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: `active_sub_menu.length` also returning `0`??

Answer (score 2):

use `length` to test if selector returns elements

```
if( $('li.show-more ul li').find('selected').length){
   $('li.show-more > a').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: it is not working, I tried `alert($('li.show-more ul li').find('qa-nav-main-selected').length);` and it return `0` but there is `selected` class in a child